# Selenium output url

Tags: selenium, junit

I need to test an output of a page without making it pop up, but just go to the url.

If you have a pdf or word export link how would you test its contents.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to step outside of Selenium

1. To test a URL without making the window pop-up, consider downloading the contents of the URL without Selenium. I'm assuming you are using Java, so look into downloading the content of a URL in java. It also depends on what you are testing, this works if you want to just check if a URL is broken or not for example.
2. To check the contents of a PDF or a Word file, you also can't use Selenium. You will need to find a Java library to parse the PDF and Word files and then use that to read the content.

As you can see both require a bit of research on your part. The key is not getting hung up on Selenium and making use of the rest of the programming language.